# Find number of five digit natural numbers using digits $1,2,3,4,5$ such that consecutive digits do not appear together

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Find number of five digit natural numbers using digits $1,2,3,4,5$ without Repetition such that consecutive digits do not appear together

I just tried in by listing the possibilities in a sequential manner:

The possibilities are:

$1)$ $13524$

$2)$ $14253$

$3)$ $24135$

$4)$ $24153$

$5)$ $25314$

$6)$ $31524$

$7)$ $35142$

$8)$ $41352$

$9)$ $42531$

$10)$ $42513$

$11)$ $52413$

$12)$ $53142$

So i got $12$ possibilities.

Is there a Mathematical or formal way to solve this and can we generalize it for $n$ digit numbers?

Comment: You left out $31425$ and $35241$

Answer (score 5):

It's all in the following picture:
$$\matrix{
&&3&&\cr
&/&&\setminus &\cr
&1\ &--&\ 5\cr
&\setminus &&/&&\cr
&\ 4&-&2\ &&\cr}$$
We can begin by $(31\ldots)$, $(13\ldots)$, $(14\ldots)$, $(41\ldots)$, and $(42\ldots)$. This will lead to $7$ strings, which then have to be multiplied by $2$ for the beginnings $(35\ldots)$, $(53\ldots)$, etcetera.

Comment: How did you come up with the diagram?

Comment: @mathnoob: Press on the "edit"; then you shall see it. It's $K_5$ minus four edges, arranged in a symmetric way.

Answer (score 1):

Possible partners for each number are 
1: 3,4,5
2: 4,5 
3: 1,5
4: 1,2
5: 1,2,3

Suppose 2 is at the left end, it may be followed by 4 or 5
in case of 4 next option is only 1 followed by 35 or 53 so we have 2 options. In case of 5 next option can only be 314. Thus 2 on left edge gives us 3 options.

By symmetry 2 on right edge will also give 3 options.

If 2 is not on edges it is sandwiched between 45 or 54. So we have 2 possibilities. 1 can be placed on either sides of 2 options giving us 4 possibilities. If 1 is near 4, 3 can be placed on other side of 1 or next to 5. if 1 is near 5, 3 can be placed on either side of 1, again multiplying possibility by 2. So we have 8 such options.

On the whole we have 3+3+8=14 strings